# Android TV - leanback library how to add more button to VideoSupportFragmentGlueHost

Tags: android, android-tv

i'm using leanback-v17:27.1.0 library and i try to custom VideoSupportFragmentGlueHost, i want to add more button here like repeat or next button
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fD3M.png)
i tried to use leanback.app.PlaybackOverlayFragment but in the leanback-v17:27 it's don't have that PlaybackOverlayFragment class like this tutorial 
http://corochann.com/android-tv-application-hands-on-tutorial-7-159.html#PlaybackOverlayFragment
someone can help me add more button to this VideoSupportFragmentGlueHost

```
 public void initData(MovieSampleResult mObject)
{
    try {
        VideoSupportFragmentGlueHost glueHost =
                new VideoSupportFragmentGlueHost(PlayFullScreenVideoFragment.this);
        MediaPlayerAdapter playerAdapter = new MediaPlayerAdapter(getContext());
        playerAdapter.setRepeatAction(PlaybackControlsRow.RepeatAction.INDEX_NONE);
        mTransportControlGlue = new PlaybackTransportControlGlue<>(getContext(), playerAdapter);
        mTransportControlGlue.setHost(glueHost);
        mTransportControlGlue.setTitle(mObject.getName());
        //mTransportControlGlue.setSubtitle(mObject.getDescription());
        playerAdapter.setDataSource(Uri.parse(mObject.getVideo()));
        Log.e("TAG PLAY FULL",mObject.getVideo());
        MyTrackApplication myTrackApplication = MyTrackApplication.getInstance();
        myTrackApplication.trackScreenView(TAGSCREEN,
                mObject.getName(),
                "Watch Video on FullScreen Mode",0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG,e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add additional actions to the default transport controls layout, you'll need to extend the `PlaybackTransportControlGlue` class and override the methods that add actions.

Below is an example that shows how to add an additional primary action (top row, above the seek bar) for skipping to the next piece of content and a secondary action (below the seek bar) for enabling closed captioning. This example uses the `MediaPlayerAdapter` class as that's what you're using in your question, but this could work with any `PlayerAdapter` implementation.

```
public class VideoPlayerGlue extends PlaybackTransportControlGlue<MediaPlayerAdapter> {

    private PlaybackControlsRow.SkipNextAction skipNextAction;
    private PlaybackControlsRow.ClosedCaptioningAction closedCaptioningAction;

    public VideoPlayerGlue(Context context, MediaPlayerAdapter impl) {
        super(context, impl);

        closedCaptioningAction = new PlaybackControlsRow.ClosedCaptioningAction(context);
        skipNextAction = new PlaybackControlsRow.SkipNextAction(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreatePrimaryActions(ArrayObjectAdapter primaryActionsAdapter) {
        super.onCreatePrimaryActions(primaryActionsAdapter); // Adds play/pause first.
        primaryActionsAdapter.add(skipNextAction); // Adds skip next second. Order matters.
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreateSecondaryActions(ArrayObjectAdapter secondaryActionsAdapter) {
        secondaryActionsAdapter.add(closedCaptioningAction); // Adds CC to row below seek bar.
    }

    @Override
    public void onActionClicked(Action action) {
        // Handle your action clicks here to allow them to interface with
        // the player and/or the PlayerAdapter.

        super.onActionClicked(action); // Allows for built-in play/pause and seek bar clicks.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to add your playback control icon just use the code below:
first import R from your project and then create your custom control class like FavoriteAction

```
class FavoriteAction(context: Context) : Action("FavAction") {
    init {
        icon = context.resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_fav)
        label1 = "favorite"
    }
}
```

then use this class in plabackControl glue as a control buttton